Unevenly spaced coordinates supposed to form a grid (Bing Tile System). Convert to tiff?
My question is similar to Join info about quadkeys to tile shapefile  at Stack Overfow and concerns the same dataset.
We have a file with lat/lon coordinate pairs in decimal degrees and some other attributes, for example
The lats spacing differs from -0.0216746 to -0.0214562 in this case. It is not evenly spaced as I would expect from the input data description.
Is there some implied transformation that I have to apply to make this data useable?
Here is how it starts with everything aligned

and this is what it looks like with the continous shift happening along both axes

I have tried using QGIS to create points layer from table and then Rasterize (vector to raster)
The software is able to read and construct a grid, but it does not account for the uneven coordinates. I guess the issue has something to do with the Bing Tiles schema used to create this data (and how it was supplied initially if we are to believe the above Stack Overflow post) but unfortunately I have no experience on working with this data. Hence my result have the first pixel aligned (talking solely about the latitude here, something similar happens for longitude but let's keep it simple) and then over the course of the whole extent it shifts more and more painting a distorted picture.

I think you should focus your question on one of the ways that you’ve tried and, if that way uses Python then please include your code attempt.
